# Make part of a Cypher query dynamic with spring data neo4j 3

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a UserRepository class that extends GraphRepository:

```
  public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

    @Query("MATCH (User:_User) WHERE User.network = {0} RETURN User")
    Iterable<User> executeFilterTest(String filterValue);

  }
```

The problem is I don't always know exactly what the 'WHERE' part of the query will have. So I want to be able to send in the WHERE part as a parameter like this:

```
    @Query("MATCH (User:_User) {0} RETURN User")
    Iterable<User> executeFilterTest(String whereValue);
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or can I somehow save the whole Cypher query as a String and then send in the whole String as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom repository example (please take not that impl method must match to your userRepository not userRepositoryCustom eg: UserRepositoryImpl) :

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, UserRepository {
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired Neo4jTemplate template;
    @Override
    public Result<Map<String, Object>> findByCypher(String cypher) {
    return template.query(cypher, null);
    }
}

public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    Result<Map<String, Object>> findByCypher(String cypher);    
}
```

Comment: UserRepository should extends UserRepositoryCustom and not UserRepository